# Ubuntu One No Referral Bonus

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one

I have set up 5 of my Friends to Ubuntu One and should have had 2.5gb of referral bonus, when I set up one of the account the website crashed which must have skipped the referral process. My friends is still able to log in and use it but neither him or me have got the 0.5gb referral.

Please help as I need the extra storage.

Comment: That's a bummer, sounds like a bug. You need to [contact support](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/) at Ubuntu One and ask them about it. Good luck.